# Detect and connect online users

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, authentication, webforms

I want to develop a website in `ASP.NET Web Forms`. In this website i want to connect any two online users randomly for a specified time *(suppose 30 seconds)*.

I am thinking to add the users into a temp table_(to keep a track of online users)_ and assign them a random number as soon as they log in and delete them from the temp table on log out.

Problems:

1. I have no idea how to remove the user from the table on session expire or on browser close.
2. I am not sure how to connect two online users randomly *(like in omegle)*. When **User A** and **User C** are connected **User B** should not be able to connect to **`User A and User C`**

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can send every 10 seconds an Ajax request informing the server "user x is currently connected with user y". In the table containing the users, you store when each user sent its last "I am still there" request by updating `lastUpdate` to the current time an `connected` to `1`. When a user is online, but not connected, you update `lastUpdate` and set `connected` to zero.

Table structure as follows:

```
users
    userId | lastUpdate | connected

connections
    userA | userB
```

When `lastUpdate` is more than 20s ago, connections with this user are most likely not alive anymore.

When connecting users randomly, you will select only users that are online (I.e. whose `lastUpdate` is fewer than 20s ago).

When connecting two users, you only choose users who aren't connected currently (`connected = 0`) and who are online (`lastUpdate` not more than 20s ago).

Comment: I have unlimited number of users, not just two users

Comment: You said you want to connect two users. Do you want to connect three or more users with each other?

Comment: I mean One on One chat...but the number of online users are unlimited.

Comment: This is possible my this approach. You need, of course, an extra user table which contains all available users. I only have mentioned the connection table, which just associates two users.

Comment: I meant "possible with my approach".